# Simple woxblom magnificent DragListView android library example

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, drag-and-drop

I found a very magnificent demo of DragListView from woxblom on github, https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView

BUT, my problem is the demo project is complex, that I can't track every single function to display only "draggable list demo". Because I really need the draggable vertically list view.

For anybody who can explain to me the simple example that only a functionality of draggable list view(only list view) without another view(Cardboard, Column, anything on the sample demo), It would be appreciated.

Sorry, If It's a dumb question. I'm just a newbie.

Thank you very much.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kpUV4x6COdI this is useful to watch

Comment: @jhegedus this is a simple recycler view nothing else. not useful.